# SQL filtering rows using WHERE clause with array_agg function and joins

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

My current query:

```
SELECT 
    i.ID AS interview_id, i.board, i.time_taken, i.notes, i.interview_date,
    u.ID AS user_id, u.first_name, u.last_name, u.state, u.district, u.optional, u.is_interview_user_only, 
    COALESCE((SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT uj.job_name) as jobs FROM user_jobs uj WHERE uj.user_id = u.id), '{}') as jobs
    FROM interview i
    JOIN users u ON i.user_id = u.id 
    GROUP BY u.id, i.id;
```

I want to implement filters for the interviews by "checking if a certain Job is in the array_agg of that interview row."

Current output:

```
interview_id | time_taken | ... | jobs
1001         | 25         | ... | {CEO, Product Manager}
1002         | 20         | ... | {Customer Care, Hospitality}
1003         | 40         | ... | {CEO, CFO}
1004         | 35         | ... | {Army Official, Sales Manager}
```

Output I want: When I mention Jobs having "CEO" as a filter/criteria

```
interview_id | time_taken | ... | jobs
1001         | 25         | ... | {CEO, Product Manager}
1003         | 40         | ... | {CEO, CFO}
```

to return rows only having "CEO" as one of the value in jobs array aggregate.

I am not sure how to use the WHERE or HAVING or IN clause with the above query so as to filter the rows based on results from the subquery aggregate array.

Is this possible in a single query where joins and aggregates are present?

If not, how else can I make this possible?

I want to implement this statement for applying sorts and filters options selected from Frontend.

Database: PostgreSQL
Environment: Node using Express and node-pg package.
Frontend: Vue

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite the query so there is no subquery.  That is, just add in `user_jobs` to the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT i.ID AS interview_id, i.board, i.time_taken, i.notes, i.interview_date,
       u.ID AS user_id, u.first_name, u.last_name, u.state, u.district, 
       u.optional, u.is_interview_user_only, 
       array_agg(DISTINCT uj.job_name) as jobs
FROM interview i
JOIN users u ON i.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN user_jobs uj ON uj.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id, i.id;
```

Now, you can add filtering in a `HAVING` clause:

```
HAVING COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE uj.job_name = 'CEO') > 0
```

Comment: I'm upvoting the answer since it's technically correct, but the choice of formatting makes it a little hard for me to follow. That's the first time I've seen the JOIN on the previous line from the joined table and the ON with the same indentation as the table names.